# Some columns not visible after reading xlsm file : Key error for specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

Column names showing in **df.columns** but not in condition ?

```
df_Client = pd.read_excel(row['SOURCE_PATH'], sheet_name='Payment Information', header=4, engine='openpyxl')
df_Client.columns = df_Client.columns.str.strip()
df_Client = df_Client.iloc[4: , :]
print(df_Client.columns)
print('Service Office' in df_Client.columns)
print('Unique Number' in df_Client.columns)
print('Email Filename' in df_Client.columns)
print('Invoice Filename' in df_Client.columns)

df_Client = df_Client[['Unique Number', 'Entity','Creditor','Payment Description','Invoice Date' ,'Invoice No.','Amount', 'Currency', 'Comments', 'Due Date', 'Service Office', 'Email Filename', 'Invoice Filename']]
df_Client = df_Client[df_Client['Unique Number'].notna()]
```

OUTPUT:

> File 1: Index(['Entity', 'Vpcode', 'counting', 'Batch No.', 'Payment
> No.', 'Creditor',
> 'Payment Description', 'Invoice Date', 'Invoice No.', 'Amount',
> 'Currency', 'Status', 'Status Date', 'Due Date', 'Comments',
> 'First / Departmental Approver', 'Bank Account', 'Doc.Holder',
> 'Invoice name', 'Service Office', 'Unique Number', 'Email Filename',
> 'Invoice Filename'],
> dtype='object') True True True True
>
> File 2: Index(['Entity', 'VP code', 'No', 'Batch No.', 'Payment No.',
> 'Creditor',
> 'Payment Description', 'Invoice Date', 'Invoice No.', 'Amount',
> 'Currency', 'Batch Status', 'Status', 'Status Date', 'Due Date',
> 'Comments', 'Yardi Upload', 'Bath Doc Holder', 'Invoice name',
> 'Service Office', 'Unique Number', 'Email Filename',
> 'Invoice Filename'],
> dtype='object')
>
> error msgs for file 2: KeyError: "['Invoice Filename', 'Service
> Office', 'Email Filename', 'Unique Number'] not in index"

Comment: Hi @Arnab! Welcome to Stackoverflow. The question is extremely difficult to read as is.  Could you try to format your question a bit clearer please? Use Code blocks (```` ... ```) for code please.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I have made some edits. Can you please take a look? @halloleo